# Adding a new account to Gmail/Youtube shows a Password Error

Tags: gmail, password, youtube, bugs

I recently goy myself a Moto G3, that is running Android 5.1.1.

I have 3 e-mail addresses, all of those I wish to keep in my Gmail app (I did that in an older phone I had), so I go to "Add Account" in the Gmail app, click "New Account" and...

I'm taken to a "Confirm your Password" screen. And there, I type my password... Only to see a "try again" prompt. And no matter how many attempts I do, all I see is a "try again" prompt. My research led me to know that a "2 step verification" can be the issue, but turns out it's deactivated on ALL 3 OF MY ACCOUNTS!

I also can't add other accounts to my Youtube app, which I need since I need to publish videos while away from my PC. Here's an image of that confirm your password screen. If anyone has any suggestions, I'll be thankfull (just a warning: I'm a noob, so I'd appreciate "simpler" language if possible).

Also, if it helps, the main account is my personal e-mail. I'd like to add 2 "workplace" e-mails to the Gmail app, and one of those is linked to a Youtube Account.

[image]
<sup>Click on it for larger version</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, updating to Android 6.0 has corrected the issue.

Answer (score 9):

At least for me, it was actually the *device* password - used to unlock the phone. So basically it asks for the device password when you try to add a new Google account for some reason. I formatted my phone thinking something else was the issue - but if you enter the device password, it then asks for the account name as normal.

Comment: This answer works.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its a typo, but you say:

> ...so I go to "Add Account" in the Gmail app, click "New Account" and...

Why do you go to "New Account" if you **already** have 3 email address?

This is how on my 5.1.1, Adding an account works:

- I go to Settings > Accounts > Add Account > Google > 'Enter email' > 'Enter password' > Logs me in

The steps you're describing isn't available, as you only need to confirm your password when creating a New Account, and not when logging into an already created account.

If you see "Confirm Password", then you're not *logging in*, but rather, *creating an account*, in this case, a 4th Google account.

Comment: I followed your steps and where you said that you had to "enter e-mail" it just showed confirm your password (the image I uploaded) and the issue happens again

Comment: Although if I click on personal (IMAP) it does let me enter my email. I assume that wouldn't work with the YouTube app since I don't see an option to add a YouTube account...